# Browser fires request twice to image handler

Tags: asp.net, image-processing

I am working on a web application. Some images are calling a web provider, which renders the picture, and send it to the client (the html looks like `img ... src="/WebProviders/ImageHandler.ashx?.../>`).

The problem I have encountered is that both IE8 and Firefox 3.6.8 fire the request to the handler more than once, yet not consistently. I could not trace a pattern (the same image sometimes cause one and sometimes several requests).

Answer (score 0):

Have you used a product like Fiddler to view the HTTP traffic from the web page to the server, that will allow you to see if that is firing two requests to the handler.

Comment: I have used Fiddler, and there I've seen the traffic, that sometimes the web-page fires one request and sometimes two in a row. I have checked it as well in Visual Studio, using a breakpoint in the image-handler and debug (attached to w3wp). again inconsistent behavior.

Comment: embarrassing, but my fault. Apparently the js code is doing some manipulation on the source string, so it is resend to the server. fixed.